# Retrieve the PHAsset localIdentifier of a UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

Goal: Let users pick photos and the app will store/retrieve/delete references to those images by storing the PHAsset.localIdentifier in Core Data.

I am successfully retrieving PHAssets from Photos, accessing the images and the local identifiers. Also storing the localIdentifier in Core Data successfully. The issue is when I need to update/delete the core data record containing the localIdentifier based on some user activity involving the image in question, I can't "reverse-lookup" the original localIdentifier associated with the image.

Is there a way to do that? Or will I have to resort to a custom construct to store the localIdentifier and image so I can relate them when needed. UIImage has an imageAsset? Not sure if that could be useful somehow.